# Why do I get results when I add an index to my RethinkDB query?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a query that returns nothing:

```
r.db('dashboard').table('phases').getAll("f9fd6d4a-1e02-3736-9efb-9b8e06db0977")
```

If I add an `index`, then I get results.  Here is an example:

```
r.db('dashboard').table('phases').getAll("f9fd6d4a-1e02-3736-9efb-9b8e06db0977", {
  index: 'drillId'
})
```

When I add an `index`, what changes in the query to give me results?  I would expect the index to just speed up the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify an index, [by default](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/get_all/) it searches in the `id` index. So if that `f9...77` is a `drillId` and not an `id`, it'll returns nothing at best, another document at worst.